# @NamedQuery over @NamedNativeQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hql

Is there any benefit of using `@NamedQuery` over `@NamedNativeQuery` in hibernate or vice verse.
I cant spot the exact difference or 
in which context we should use `@NamedQuery` over `@NamedNativeQuery`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`@NamedNativeQuery` lets you write a named SQL query, while `@NamedQuery` lets you write a named HQL query (or JPQL).

In general, you should prefer to write HQL queries because then you can let Hibernate handle the intricacies of converting the HQL into the various SQL dialects. This will make your job much simpler when you choose to switch DBMS providers.

Answer (score 11):

When taking about performance, you have to know something about what goes on under the hood.

You have probably programmed something using straightforward JDBC, so you know how to queries
get passed to the driver and send to the database. When using HQL or JPA-QL the queries first have
to be parsed into an SQL language that the database can understand. In this case, we have an extra
parsing step in between. Note that Native SQL queries, including stored procedure calls, the persistence
framework still takes care of mapping the JDBC result sets to graphs of persistent objects.

If you want to include a native SQL hint to instruct the database management systems query optimizer,
for example, you need to write the SQL yourself. HQL and JPA-QL do not have keywords for this.

The disadvantage of putting native SQL in your mapping metadata is lost database portability, because
your mappings, and hence your application, will work only for a particular database. But usually this is of a
minor concern as you are probably not creating a framework that has to work on every database.

When you want to get behind the performance of your query, you really have to consult the database
and look at the execution plan - A DBA can tell you exactly what is good and what can be optimized.

Answer (score 9):

`@NamedQuery` should be constructed with the query language (HQL or persistence query language).  `@NamedNativeQuery` should be constructed with native SQL.